# Merge two table columns without join query

Tags: mysql, join, union

I am making project in Laravel. I have multiple tables of which two table are books and authors.
Author has columns :

```
-id
 -name
 -all_books(',' separated values)
 -recent_books
 Books has columns :
 -id
 -author_id(foreign key(from author table))
 -title
 -genre
 -pages
```

Now, i want to fetch all data of books. But instead of author_id i want to display author name
How is it possible. Join will force me to put condition. so don't wanna do it.
Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean JOIN will force you to use conditions?

Comment: can i join the table without condition??

Comment: If you want to display a corresponding data from another table, you need to tell mysql how to combine the two tables. It is possible without join as you can see from the answer below, but the correlated subquery also has a "condition" to fetch the right name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As author id is unique so there is no chance multiple author name with same id. So corelated subquery will always return single value. So no JOIN is needed.

```
SELECT b.id
     , (SELECT name FROM author WHERE id = b.author_id) author_name
     , b.title
     , b.genre
     , b.pages
FROM books b
```

Comment: How can i do it in laravel?

Comment: Hi @Milanjotva As you mentioned mysql tag so that I'm answering this. I'm not laravel expert. But you can convert mysql code to laravel from https://jjlabajo.github.io/SQLtoEloquent/     "Laravel code" :    DB::table("books b")
->select("b.id", "(select name from author where id = b.author_id) author_name", "b.title", "b.genre", "b.pages")
->get();

Comment: Please check this. If my answer helps you then please mark it as accepted along with upvote so any one can pick this without any doubt.